# 4-Vector Potential, transformation under Lorenz Gauge

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge

I am given an initial vector potential let's say:

\begin{equation}
 \vec{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
   g(t,x)\\
   f(t,y)\\
   0\\
   g(t,x)\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

i think you are misunderstanding slightly, to obtain your potentials, you must have a specific chosen gauge that these potentials satisfy already.

Suppose my vector potential satisfies a specific gauge already,

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{A} = G(x,y,z,t)$$

I now perform a gauge transformation,
$\vec{A} \rightarrow \vec{A}'$ such that:

$\vec{A}' = \vec{A} +\nabla f$

$\phi' = \phi -\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$

These leave the field invariant

Suppose that these transformations also  satisfy:

$\nabla \cdot \vec{A}' +\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial\phi'}{\partial t}=0$

substitute the definition of the transformed potentials  $\vec{A}' \phi'$ into our expression:

$\nabla \cdot [\vec{A} +\nabla f] +\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial[\phi -\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}]}{\partial t}=0$

$\nabla \cdot \vec{A} + \nabla^2f + \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} -\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t^2} = 0$

$  \nabla^2f  -\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t^2} = -[\nabla \cdot \vec{A}  + \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}]$

Here we have an equation for f, that would need to be used in order to transform our potentials in the lorentz gauge.

Plugging in our known value for the original gauge that my untransformed potentials satify ( something which you havent mentioned yet), and time derivative for the scalar potential we obtain our f.

From our obtained value of f, we then transform the potentials that we have defined earlier.

$\vec{A}' = \vec{A} +\nabla f$

Our new potential $\vec{A}'$ thus satisfies the lorentz gauge whilst leaving the field B invariant.

Comment: note: the problem as set up _does_ specify the gauge that the field satisfies, which is evidently $\nabla \cdot A = 0$. But that is a minor point and otherwise you are correct that this means that indeed the next step is to solve $\nabla^2 f - \ddot f/c^2 = \dot\phi$.

Comment: @CRDrost I don't think that the problem "does specify the gauge the field satisfies..." At least, it is not clear to me. OP only writes that A = (g ,0, 0, g) and then write that he wants to perform a "Lorenz gauge transformation." This is unclear because it could be that OP is saying that already $\partial g/\partial t + \partial g/\partial z = 0$, or OP could be saying that $g$ is arbitrary and OP wants to **find** a transformation $A\to A+\partial\chi$ such that $-\partial^2\chi =\partial g/\partial t + \partial g/\partial z$.

Comment: @hft Indeed I made a mistake above, I meant that $\nable \cdot A = 0 $. So now we have a partial differential equation to solve. Could you pls read the continuation of my question above with the new clues.

Comment: if the divergence of your original vector potential is in the coulomb gauge, how are you finding the time derivatives of the scalar potential to solve for f?

Comment: @jensenpaull. Could you explain a bit more your question ols?